# What is the advantage of using ngModel over input/event binding, template variable binding and using banana syntax - approaches for 2-way binding

Tags: angular

When developing Angular application, to achieve 2-way binding, what is the advantage of using the [(ngModel)] approach (shown below) over the following 3 approaches (also listed below). Also, which amongst the foll. are the best options to achieve 2 way data binding (whether building forms or in general (non-form) use-case scenario)?

**[(ngModel)] approach:**

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="varName">

<--OR-->

<input [ngModel]="varName" (ngModelChange)="SomeFunction($event.target.value)">
```

**1. Input/event binding as follows:**

```html
<input [value]="aVar" (input)="aVar=$event.target.value" >
    {{aVar}}
```

**2. Template variable as follows:**

```html
    <input [value]="bVar" (input)="bVar=ipx.value" #ipx>
{{bVar}}
```

**3. Banana syntax approach:**

```html
 <input ([value])="cVar">
{{cVar}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. NgModel**

```
<!-- Will not work should replace with below No One -->
<input [ngModel]="varName" (ngModelChange)="SomeFunction($event.target.value)">

<!-- One -->
<input [ngModel]="varName" (ngModelChange)="varName = $event">
```

**2. Property Binding**

```
<input [value]="aVar" (input)="aVar=$event.target.value" >
```

**3. #ipx** call as element reference, it will give you element reference.

> No 4 **Banana syntax approach:** will not work `<input ([value])="cVar">`. Because `value` is not a angular directive, while ngModel is a directive belongs to FormsModule.`

- `NgModel` is an abstraction over all kinds of elements and components.
- While `template reference (#ipx)` will only works for input elements that have a value property and emit a change event.
- `[value]="aVar"` is the property binding. We are binding value property of the input element with expression name.
  (input)= "expression" is event binding. Whenever input event will be fired expression will be executed.
- `[(ngModel)]="varName"` is the short form of `[ngModel]="varName" (ngModelChange)="varName = $event"`
- Using the NgModel directive that will allows you to integrate DOM input elements and custom components into Angular form functionality.

**Conclusion :**

- We can conclude that the directive ngModel is nothing but a combination of property binding and event binding.
- `Event binding is denoted using small bracket` and `property binding is denoted using square [] bracket`, and if you notice `syntax of ngModel is [(ngModel)], which is like a banana` put into a box suggests it is combination of both event and property binding.

Reference [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwqcjr)